# run docker Rstudio server without root?

Tags: docker

I just started playing with docker. The first thing I did was to install it, and then install Rstudio-server. (I'm running ubuntu 14.04)

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
sudo docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e USER='some_user_name' -e PASSWORD='super_secret_password' rocker/hadleyverse
```

Is it possible to run a docker rstudio server without sudo? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo):

The [docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#giving-non-root-access) has this to say about it:

> **Giving non-root access**
>
> The docker daemon always runs as the root user, and since Docker version 0.5.2, the docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root, and so, by default, you can access it with sudo.
>
> Starting in version 0.5.3, if you (or your Docker installer) create a Unix group called docker and add users to it, then the docker daemon will make the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group when the daemon starts. The docker daemon must always run as the root user, but if you run the docker client as a user in the docker group then you don't need to add sudo to all the client commands. As of 0.9.0, you can specify that a group other than docker should own the Unix socket with the -G option.
>
> **Warning: The docker group (or the group specified with -G) is root-equivalent; see [Docker Daemon Attack Surface details](https://docs.docker.com/articles/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface).**
>
> **Example:**

- Add the docker group if it doesn't already exist.

  ```
  sudo groupadd docker
  ```
- Add the connected user "${USER}" to the docker group. Change the user name to match your preferred user.

  ```
  sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
  ```
- Restart the Docker daemon:

  ```
  sudo service docker restart
  ```
- If you are on Ubuntu 14.04 and up use `docker.io` instead:

  ```
  sudo service docker.io restart
  ```
- **You need to log out and log back in again if you added the current logged in user.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm liking this a lot!